# When I use typescript, how can I use the cookie-parser of express

Tags: express, typescript, typescript-typings

I want to use cookie-parser in expressjs, but typescript can't find the type of request.cookie. How can I solve it?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hk81.png)

Comment: I think you need the .d.ts definition file for express cookies?

Comment: I've tried, But it didn't work.  The  interface of Request is in namespace of req in express. I think I should modify the express.d.ts

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: use (<any> request).cookie  or (request as any).cookie.

Answer (score 8):

Just make sure that you've imported `Request` type from express package instead of native request declaration type.

```
import {Request} from 'express';
```